# Show header below fixed nav when clicking hash tag link

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed navigation bar. Its menu items link to a bookmark with a hash tag: `example.html#bookmark`

When the hash tag link is clicked, the `<h1 id="bookmark">Bookmark</h1>` should show, just below the nav, like this:

> [image: What should happen]

But currently, the heading element is being overlapped by the fixed header navigation bar:

> [image: What actually happens]

How can this be prevented?

**The HTML and CSS:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  height: 80px;
  background: #EEE;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
.header a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/*Ignore below this. This just creates padding for the example to scroll*/

body:before,
body:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a href="#bookmark">Click this link to take you to the anchor</a>
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet auctor tellus. Integer imperdiet urna vulputate pellentesque consectetur. Donec bibendum mi ac augue maximus, a porttitor risus faucibus. Aenean dui nisi, ornare et auctor vel, condimentum
  vel lorem. Aliquam et mollis nisi, nec auctor diam. Ut sollicitudin vel nisl vel condimentum. Quisque ut nisl lobortis, blandit ante vitae, pellentesque lectus.</p>


<h1 id="bookmark">Bookmark</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet auctor tellus. Integer imperdiet urna vulputate pellentesque consectetur. Donec bibendum mi ac augue maximus, a porttitor risus faucibus. Aenean dui nisi, ornare et auctor vel, condimentum
  vel lorem. Aliquam et mollis nisi, nec auctor diam. Ut sollicitudin vel nisl vel condimentum. Quisque ut nisl lobortis, blandit ante vitae, pellentesque lectus.</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple workaround. Give the linked element a suitable large top padding, and cancel it out with an equal negative margin:

```
h1 {
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
}
```

The linked element moves the viewport to the top of the elements padding and the negative margin removes the extra whitespace.

#### Example

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
  height: 80px;
  background: #EEE;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
.header a {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1 {
  margin-top: -80px;
  padding-top: 80px;
}

/*Ignore below this. This just creates padding for the example to scroll*/
body:before,
body:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <a href="#bookmark">Click this link to take you to the anchor</a>
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris sit amet auctor tellus. Integer imperdiet urna vulputate pellentesque consectetur. Donec bibendum mi ac augue maximus, a porttitor risus faucibus. Aenean dui nisi, ornare et auctor vel, condimentum</p>

<h1 id="bookmark">Bookmark</h1>
<p>vel lorem. Aliquam et mollis nisi, nec auctor diam. Ut sollicitudin vel nisl vel condimentum. Quisque ut nisl lobortis, blandit ante vitae, pellentesque lectus.</p>
```

---

#### Limitation

A limitation of this workaround is the padding that is now underneath the text  above the linked element. Any background colour of the linked element would show underneath and **this would require its own workaround** :)

[image: Limitation]